# How does Tarjan's pseudocode work (explained to someone familiar with C or Java)?

Tags: programming-languages

## The Short Story

A famous computer scientist, [Tarjan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Tarjan), wrote a book years ago. It contains absolutely bizarre pseudocode. Would someone please explain it?

## The Long Story

[Tarjan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Tarjan) is known for many accomplishments, including the fact that he was the coinventor of [splay trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splay_tree). He published a book, "*Data Structures and Network Algorithms*," during the 1980s.

All of the pseudo-code in Tarjan's book is written in a language of his own devising. The pseudo-code conventions are very regimented. It's almost a true language, and one could imagine writing a compiler for it. Tarjan writes that his language is based upon the following three:

- [Dijkstra's Guarded Command Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guarded_Command_Language)
- [SETL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SETL)
- [ALGOL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algol)

I am hoping that someone familiar with one or two of the above languages, or the work of Tarjan, will be able to answer my question.

An example of a function written in Tarjan's language is shown below:

```
heap function mesh (heap nodes h1, h2);

    if key(h1) > key(h2) → h1 ⟷  h2 fi;

    right (h1) := if right(h1) = null → h2

                  |right(h1) ≠ null → mesh (right(h1), h2) fi;

    if rank (left (h1)) < rank (right (h1)) → left(h1) ⟷ right(h1) fi;

    rank (h1) := rank(right(h1)) + 1;

    return h1,

end mesh;
```

I have seen lots of pseudo-code, but I have never seen anything like Tarjan's. How does Tarjan's pseudocode work? How can examples of Tarjan's pseudocode be re-written as something which looks more like C or Java? It need not even be C or Java. The if-else construct in Tarjan's language is not only different from C-family languages, but also different from Python, MATLAB and many others.

Comment: What, specifically, do you not understand? What explanation of syntax and semantics is given in the book?

Comment: Did you copy the sample from somewhere or transcribe it yourself? Are the last two lines inside the function body really not indented more? And does the `return` statement really end in a comma?

Comment: @Bergi, yes the last two lines of the function body for the function named `mesh` were supposed to be indented more.

Comment: @Bergi You asked me to explain where I copied the samples of pseudo-code from or whether I transcribed the pseudo-code myself. I **imperfectly** copied, or transcribed, the samples from a book titled, "Data Structures and Network Algorithms" by Robert Endre Tarjan published in 1983 by the Society for Industrial and Applied Mathematics having International Standard Book Number 9780898711875, 0898711878. I do not know where to find a machine-readable copy of the book, and I do not know what website you can use to press `Ctrl-C` or `Ctrl-V` for copy and paste.

Comment: @ToothpickAnemone No worries. Since it doesn't change the answers, just [edit] your question to fix the transcription errors.

Answer (score 64):

## Table of Contents

I will divide my explanation of [Tarjan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Tarjan)'s pseudocode into the following sections:

1. **Tarjan's If-else Blocks (the `->` & `|` operators)**
2. **Assignment and Equality Tests (`:=` and `=`)**
3. **There is `else if`, but no `else` construct**
4. **Tarjan's Conditional Assignment Operator `:= if`**
5. **Additional Examples of Tarjan's `if` and `:= if`**
   5.5.
   **Tarjan Arrays (or Lists)**
6. **Summary of Operators**
7. **Tarjan's Double-pointed Arrow Operator (`⟷`)**
8. **Tarjan's do-loops are like C/Java while-loops**
9. **Tarjan's Conditional-assignment operator with all false conditions**

---

## (1) Tarjan's If-else Blocks

## (the operators `→` and `|` )

The `if-else` construct is perhaps the most fundamental control structure in Tarjan's language.

In Tarjan's pseudo-code, every while-loop and assignment statement has an if-statement or if-else statement built into it.

Tarjan's arrow operator `->` (or →) is a delimiter between the condition of a if-statement and the execution block of an if-statement.

For example, in Tarjan's language we might have:

```
# Example One
 if a = 4 → x := 9 fi
```

If we begin translating the line of Tarjan code above into C or Java, we might obtain the following intermediate result:

```
if (a = 4)
    x := 9
fi
```

Instead of a right curly braces (as in C and Java) Tarjan ends an `if`-block with an ALGOL-like backwards spelling of the key-word: `fi`

If we continue translating our above example, we get:

```
    if (a = 4) {
        x := 9
    }
```

#(2) Assignment and Equality Tests (`:=` and `=`)

Tarjan takes these operators from ALGOL (later also seen in Pascal).

Tarjan uses `=` for equality tests, not assignments (so it works like `==` in the [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)) programming language).

For assignment, Tarjan uses `:=`, which works like Java `=`.

Thus, if we continue translating our example, we have:

```
if (a == 4) {
    x = 9;
}
```

The if-statement provided above is syntactically correct for C-family languages such as C itself, C++, and [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language)).

In somthing halfway between English and computer code, we have:

```
if
    the memory address labeled `a` contains the number `4`
then
    store the number `9` in the memory address labeled `x`
```

---

#### Else Clauses

A vertical bar (or "pipe" or `|`) in Tarjan's language is equivalent to the `else if` keyword in C or Java.
For example, in Tarjan's language we might have:

```
# Example Two
if a = 4 → x := 9 | a > 4 → y := 11 fi
```

The Tarjan-code above translates to:

```
// This is C-style syntax   

if (a == 4) {
    x = 9; 
}
else if (a > 4) {
    y = 11;   
}
```

---

## (3) `else if` only and no `else` construct

We have gone over the basics of Trajan's `if`-statements without describing the nuances.

We will now discuss a small detail.

The last clause in one of Tarjan's `if-else` blocks must always contain an arrow (`→`) operator.

There is no `else` keyword in Tarjan's language; there is only somthing analygous to `else if`.

The closest thing to an `else`-block in Tarjan's language is to make the rightmost test-condition `true`.

```
# Tarjan Syntax

if a = 4 → x := 9 |  a > 4  → y := 11 | true  → z := 99  fi
```

In C/Java, we would have:

```java
// C-style or Java-style syntax.  
  
if (a == 4) {
     x = 9;
}
else if (a > 4)  {
    y = 11;
}
else { // else if (true)
    z = 99;
}
```

Examples are easier to understand than general descriptions.

However, now that we have some examples under our belt, know that the general formal of a Tarjan's if-else construct is as follows:

```
    if condition
        → stuff to do
     | condition
        → stuff to do
     [...] 
     | condition 
        → stuff to do
    fi
```

The character  `|` is like `if else`

The character `→` separates the test-condition from the stuff-to-do.

---

## (4) Tarjan's Conditional Assignment Operator `:= if`

Tarjan's `if` can be used two very different ways. So far, we have only described the C-style use of a Tarjan `if`.

Somewhat confusingly, Tarjan still uses the notation/syntax `if` for assignment statements.

Whether and `if` statement is an assignment-statment or not is dependent upon whether or not the `if` is preceded by an assignment operator.

For example, we might have the following Tarjan code:

```
# Example Three
x := if a = 4 → 9 fi
```

---

#### Begin Digression

After working with Tarjan code for awhile, you get used to the order of operations. If we parenthesize test condition in the example above, we obtain:

```
x := (if (a = 4) → 9 fi)
```

`a = 4` is not an assignment operation. `a = 4` is like `a == 4` -- it returns true or false.

#### End Digression

---

It can help to think of `:= if` as syntax for a single operator, distinct from `:=` and `if` In fact, we will refer to the `:= if` operator as the "conditional assignment" operator.

For `if` we list `(condition → action)`. For `:= if` we list `(condition → value)` where `value` is teh right-hand-side value we might assign to the left-hand-side `lhs`

```
# Example Four in Tarjan-Code
lhs := if (a = 4) → rhs fi
```

In C or Java, it might look like:

```
# Example Four
if (a == 4) {
    lhs = rhs;  
}
```

For reader's whose first language is not English, note that `lhs` is a common abbreviation for `left-hand side` and `rhs` is `right-hand side`.

Consider the following example of "conditional assignment" in Tarjanian code:

```
# The Tarjanian Instantiation of Example Five

x := if a = 4 → 9 |  a > 4  → 11 | true  → 99  fi
```

In C/Java, we would have:

```
    // C/Java Instantiation of Example Five
    if (a == 4) {
        x = 9;
    }
    else if (a > 4)  {
        x = 11;
    }
    else if (true) { // else
        x = 99;
    }
```

---

## (5) Summary of Operators:

So far, we have:

- `:=` ...... Assignment operator (C/Java `=`)
- `=` ...... Equality test (C/Java `==`)
- `→` ...... Delimiter between test-condition of an if-block and the body of an if-block
- `|` ..... C/Java else-if
- `if ... fi` ..... if-else block
- `:= if... fi` ..... Conditional assignment based on an if-else block

#(5.5) Tarjan Lists/Arrays:

Tarjan's Language has built-in array-like containers. The syntax for Tarjan arrays is much more intuitive than the notation for Tarjan `if else` statements.

```
list1  := ['lion', 'witch', 'wardrobe'];
list2a := [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
list2b := [1, 2];
list3  := ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
list4  := [ ]; # an empty array
```

Tarjan array elements are accessed with parentheses `()`, not square-brackets `[]`

Indexing begins at `1`. Thus,

```
list3  := ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
# list3(1) == "a" returns true
# list3(2) == "b" return true
```

Below shows how to create a new array containing the 1st and 5th elements of `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]`

```
nums := [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
new_arr := [nums(1), nums(5)]
```

The equality operator is defined for arrays. The following code prints `true`

```
x := false
if [1, 2] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] --> x := true
print(x)
```

Tarjan's way to test if an array is empty is to compare it to an empty array

```
arr := [1, 2]
print(arr = [ ])
# `=` is equality test, not assignment
```

One can create a view (not copy) of a sub-array, by providing multiple indices to operator `()` combined with `..`

```
list3  := ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

beg    := list3(.. 2)
# beg == ["a", "b"]
# beg(1) == "a"

end    := list3(3..)
# end == ["c", "d"]
# end(1) == "c"

mid    := list3(2..3)
# mid == ["b", "c"]
# mid(2) == "c"

# `list3(4)` is valid, but `mid(4)` is not
```

#(6) Additional Examples of Tarjan's `if` and `:= if`

The following is another examples of an Tarjan conditional assignment (`:= if`):

```
# Tarjan Example Six
a  := (false --> a | true --> b | false --> c1 + c2 |  (2 + 3 < 99) --> d)
```

`(true --> b)` is the leftmost `(cond --> action)` clause having a true condition.
Thus, the original assignment Example Six has the same assignment-behavior as `a := b`

Below is our most complicated example of Tarjan code thus far:

```
# Tarjan Example -- merge two sorted lists

list function merge (list s, t);

return if s =[] --> t
        | t = [ ] --> s
        | s != [ ] and t != [] and s(l) <= t(1) -->
            [s(1)]& merge(s[2..], t)
        | s != [ ]and t != [ ] and s(1) > r(l) -->
            [t(1)] & merge (s,t(2..))
       fi
end merge;
```

The following is a translation of Tarjan's code for merging two sorted lists. The following is not exactly C or Java, but it is much closer to C/Java than the Tarjan version.

```
list merge (list s, list t) { 

    if (s is empty) {
        return t;
    }
    else if (t is empty){
        return s;
    }
    else if  (s[1] <= t[1]) {
        return CONCATENATE([s[1]], merge(s[2...], t));
    else  { // else if (s[1] > t[1])
        return CONCATENATE ([t[1]], merge(s,t[2..]);
    }
}
```

Below is yet another example of Tarjan-code and a translation in something similar to C or Java:

```
heap function meld (heap h1, h2);

    return if h1 = null --> h2
            | h2 = null --> h1
            | h1 not null and h2 not null --> mesh (h1, h2) 
           fi
end meld;
```

Below is the C/Java translation:

```
HeapNode meld (HeapNode h1, HeapNode h2) {

    if (h1 == null) {
       return h2;
    }   
    else if (h2 == null) {
        return h1;
    } else {
        mesh(h1, h2)
    }
} // end function
```

#(7) Tarjan's Double-pointed Arrow Operator (`<-->`)

Below is an example of Tarjan code:

```
x <--> y
```

What Does a Double Arrow (`⟷`) Operator Do in Tarjan's Language?
Well, almost all variables in Tarjan's Language are pointers.
`<-->` is a swap operation. The following prints `true`

```
x_old := x
y_old := y
x <--> y
print(x == y_old) # prints true
print(y == x_old) # prints true
```

After performing `x <--> y`, `x` points to the object which `y` used to point to and `y` points to the object which `x` used to point to.

Below is a Tarjan statement using the `<-->` operator:

```
x := [1, 2, 3]
y := [4, 5, 6]
x <--> y
```

Below is a translation from the Tarjan code above to alternative pseudocode:

```
Pointer X     = address of array [1, 2, 3];
Pointer Y     = address of array [4, 5, 6];
Pointer X_OLD = address of whatever X points to;
X = address of whatever Y points to;
Y = address of whatever X_OLD points to;
```

Alternatively, we could have:

```
void operator_double_arrow(Array** lhs, Array** rhs) {

    // swap lhs and rhs

    int** old_lhs = 0;
    old_lhs = lhs;
    *lhs = *rhs;
    *rhs = *old_lhs;
    return;
}

int main() {

    Array* lhs = new Array<int>(1, 2, 3);
    Array* rhs = new Array<int>(4, 5, 6);
    operator_double_arrow(&lhs, &rhs);
    delete lhs;
    delete rhs;
    return 0;
}
```

Below is an example of one of Tarjan's functions using the `⟷` operator:

```
heap function mesh (heap nodes h1, h2);
    if key(h1) > key(h2) → h1 ⟷  h2 fi;
    right (h1) := if right(h1) = null → h2
                   |right(h1) ≠ null → mesh (right(h1), h2)
                  fi;

    if rank (left (h1)) < rank (right (h1))
        → left(h1) ⟷ right(h1)
    fi;

    rank (h1) := rank(right(h1)) + 1;
    return h1;
end mesh;
```

Below is a translation of Tarjan's `mesh` function into pseudo-code which is not C, but looks more like C (relatively speaking). The purpose of this is to illustrate how Tarjan's `⟷` operator works.

```
node pointer function mesh(node pointers h1, h2) {

    if (h1.key) > h2.key) {

         // swap h1 and h2
            node pointer temp;
            temp = h1;
            h1 = h2;
            h2 = temp;
    }

    // Now, h2.key <= h1.key   

    if (h1.right == null) {
        h1.right = h2;

    } else // h1.key != null {
        h1.right = mesh(h1.right, h2);
    }



    if (h1.left.rank < h1.right.rank ) {
        // swap h1.left and h1.right

        node pointer temp;
        temp = h1;
        h1 = h2;
        h2 = temp;
    }

    h1.rank = h1.right.rank + 1;
    return h1;
}
```

#(8) Tarjan's do-loops are like C/Java while-loops

Tarjan's language `if` and `for` constructs are familiar for C/Java programmers. However, the Tarjan keyword for a while-loop is `do`. All `do`-loops end with the keyword `od`, which is the backwards spelling of `do`. Below is an example:

```
sum := 0
do  sum < 50 → sum := sum + 1
```

In C-style pseudocode, we have:

```
sum = 0;
while(sum < 50) {
    sum = sum + 1;
}
```

The above is actually not quite right. A Tarjan do-loop is really a C/Java `while(true)` with an if-else block nested inside. A more literal translation of the Tarjan code is as follows:

```
sum = 0;
while(true) {
    if (sum < 50) {
         sum = sum + 1;
         continue;
         // This `continue` statement is questionable
    }
    break;
}
```

Below, we have a more complicated Tarjan `do`-loop:

```
sum := 0
do  sum < 50 → sum := sum + 1 | sum < 99 → sum := sum + 5
```

C/Java-style pseudocode for the complicated Tarjan `do`-loop is as follows:

```
sum = 0;
while(true) {

    if (sum < 50) {
         sum = sum + 1;
         continue;
    }
    else if (sum < 99) {
         sum = sum + 5;
         continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

## (9) Tarjan's Conditional-assignment operator with all false conditions

Although the lengthy explanation above covers most things, a few matters are still left unresolved.
I hope that someone else will someday write a new-improved answer based on mine which answers these quandries.

Notably, when the conditional assignment operator `:= if`  is used, and no condition is true, I am not what value is assigned to the variable.

```
x  := if (False --> 1| False --> 2 | (99 < 2) --> 3) fi
```

I am not sure, but it is possible that no assignment is made to `x`:

```
x = 0;
if (false) {
     x = 1;
}
else if (false) {
     x = 2;
}
else if (99 < 2) {
     x = 3;
}
// At this point (x == 0)
```

You could require that the left-hand-side variable seen in an `:= if`  statement be previously declared. In that case, even if all conditions are false, the variable will still have a value.

Alternatively, perhaps all-false conditions represents a runtime error. Another alternative is to return a special `null` value, and store `null` in the left-hand argument of the assignment.

Comment: I think simply implementing an interpreter/translator and/or writing an operational semantics would have been a more valuable way to use your time with regards to this.

Comment: It's worth noting that some of these features are more "exotic" than others. For instance, there are probably as many languages where `=` means comparison as where it means assignment (if I ever wrote a language, I'd make it a syntax error, and just have `:=` and `==`). On the other hand, the swap operator is the kind of thing that would only occur in specialised languages where it was a common operation; in other languages, though, you could just assume a library function called `swap` and replace `h1 ⟷  h2` with `swap(h1, h2)` rather than writing out the implementation every time.

Comment: @Raphael Tarjan's if-else is not quite the ternary operator from C-family languages. Notably, Tarjan's if-else doesn't have an else-clause. It is a bit like `C ? T` without the `: E` at the end. Writing a C-style ternary statement with an empty/null else clause is a little [tricky](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12260777/11010531)

Comment: Why is `[1, 2] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` true?

Comment: Your `do`-loop examples don't have an `od`.

Comment: The `|` operator is a *guard*. They are used in Haskell (and I believe other functional languages) in function definitions: `f x | x == 0 = 1; x == 1 = 1; otherwise = f (x-1) + f(x-2)` here `otherwise` is an alias for `True` and `f` defines the fibonacci numbers.

Comment: Array comparison example mentioned by @Erhannis also seem to lack `fi`.

Comment: @Erhannis Because the elements in the array `[1, 2]` exist in the array `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. The `=` operator when applied to arrays seems to not be direct equality but rather a subset equality. (i.e. `array1 = array2` is true if `array1` is a subset of `array2`, meaning every element in `array1` is present in `array2`.)

Comment: I wouldn't describe the `x := if … fi` as some special "conditional assignment", in some languages such as Ruby or Bourne Shell it's completely normal that that the whole if…fi block acts as an _expression_ and has its own value: a feature that _may_ be used within assignments, but isn't tied to it.

Comment: @DerekElkins Why do you think so? Compared to simply writing up one's understanding in natural language (to a level of detail sufficient to be understood by other humans), both activities you mention would take substantially longer as far as I can tell. It's not clear that it would be a more valuable use of time (especially if the goal being sought is primarily *understanding*).

Comment: I recognise the if-fi and do-od from Algol68. That's fun to read !

Comment: @grawity Well, C lost one feature when it was derived from BCPL - the valof { resultis ... } construct which allows a block to return a value rather like an anonymous function.

Comment: This deterministic interpretation if `if .. fi` and `do .. od` is at odds with Dijkstra's GCL. How can you be sure that yours is the right one?

Answer (score 8):

Never seen this before but I think I can infer what's meant from context.. Presumably the `⟷`  must be a swap operation, and `if G1 -> S1 | G2 - >S2 | ... fi` is an if/then/else-type construct that also returns a value, like the ternary `?:` operator in C and Java.

With that in hand we could write the above function in a Java-like language like so:

```
HeapNode mesh(HeapNode h1, HeapNode h2)
{
  if(h1.key > h2.key)
  {
    // swap h1 and h2

    HeapNode t = h1;
    h1 = h2;
    h2 = t;
  }

  // One of the two cases has to hold in this case so we won't get to the
  // exception, but it'd be an exception if none of the cases were satisified
  // since this needs to return *something*.

  h1.right = (h1.right == null) ? h2 
             : (h1.right != null) ? mesh(h1.right, h2) 
             : throw new Exception();

  if(h1.left.rank < h1.right.rank)
  {
    // swap h1.left and h1.right

    HeapNode t = h1.left;
    h1.left = h1.right;
    h1.right = t;
  }

  h1.rank = h1.right.rank + 1;

  return h1;
}
```